# Lua table->address and address->table

Tags: pointers, lua, lua-table

Imagine the following code:

```
Mytable={}
print(Mytable)
```

Prints something like `Table: 12345`.
How do I get the "address" part from Lua without messing with `tostring`'s return value, and more importantly, how do I get the table back?

In code:

```
addr=table2address(Mytable)
-- type(addr) is number, addr is 12345
Othertable=address2table(addr)
-- type(Othertable) is table, Othertable==Mytable is true (same reference)
```

Is there any way to implement these 2 functions in Lua? If not, (how) do I do this in C?

Edit: the `table2address` could be done by cutting the `Table:` off from `tostring(Mytable)`, but only if metamethod `__tostring` isn't defined, so I want to avoid this.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: @nonchip As you can see in @DougCurrie's answer, a table (or any value except `nil`) can be used as a table key. That satisfies almost every need for what you are asking. Do you have a special case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trivial implementation meets all your criteria but one:

```
function table2address(Mytable) return Mytable end
function address2table(addr) return addr end
```

demo:

```
> Mytable={}
> print(Mytable)
table: 0x7fe511c0a190
> addr = table2address(Mytable)
> Othertable=address2table(addr)
> =type(Othertable)
table
> print(Othertable==Mytable)
true
```

A slightly more complicated implementation meets all your criteria:

```
t2at = {}

function table2address(Mytable) 
  local addr = t2at[Mytable]
  if addr == nil then
    addr = #t2at + 1
    t2at[Mytable] = addr
    t2at[addr] = Mytable
  end
  return addr
end

function address2table(addr)
  return t2at[addr]
end
```

demo:

```
> Mytable={}
> addr = table2address(Mytable)
> Othertable=address2table(addr)
> =type(Othertable)
table
> print(Othertable==Mytable)
true
> =type(addr)
number
```

So, why is the address important to you?

In a garbage collected language such as Lua, it is only possible to hold a reference to an object, not an address. [The present implementation may or may not move objects during GC, but other than `userdata` and Lua states, Lua has license to move anything.]

ADDENDUM

Re: "the addresses never get randomized (try print({}) in 2 new interactive lua instances)"

```
e$ lua
Lua 5.2.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print({})
table: 0x7fdaca4098c0
> ^D
e$ lua
Lua 5.2.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print({})
table: 0x7fb02a4098c0
> ^D
e$
```

Re: the physical address is really needed

Look at the function `luaL_tolstring` that implements the guts of print; it has (in Lua 5.2.2):

```
  default:
    lua_pushfstring(L, "%s: %p", luaL_typename(L, idx),
                                        lua_topointer(L, idx));
    break;
```

So, `lua_topointer(L, idx)` is the function you need to get a table's address.

Comment: +1 Well done! Meets the stated criteria while avoiding implementation details.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but both of your approaches fail the criteria: the first one is a bad joke, just returning the input. The second implements a numeric auto-growing lookup table. None of these even look at the table's address.

Comment: To answer your questions: the address is important to me because it's obviosly possible to get it from lua (see tostring), so it exists and can be used to refer to the table. And as the addresses never get randomized (try `print({})` in 2 new interactive lua instances) they can be used to address the same table process-independently. I know that's not reliable, but as I'm trying to implement some freezercode-like function as a techdemo, the user is encouraged to experiment with the values anyway.

Comment: In other words: I'm aware of the many list/array/whatever implementations out there, so the address really is the only thing important because I do'nt want any list/lookuptable/... but just a peek/poke equivalent functionality.

Comment: @nonchip, See my addendum that addresses your comments.

Comment: About the address getting randomized on your host: that's strange, on my machine it isn't, and the addresses also are much smaller/shorter. Seems I got a VM version with local address management or my kernel is misconfigured.

Comment: its worth noting that some lua hosts will actually obscure the table address for security reasons (and some consider it a bug that its ever made availible). At the very least, theres no assurance that this is portable.

Comment: If I wanted to exchange tables between two seperately running lua scripts, this won't do it